# Unexpected Behaviour When using Keyboard.read_key()

Tags: python, keyboard

I am tying to make a program in which I press certain hot key which will then detect a key press and tell which key I pressed but whenever I press the hotkey, program doesn't respond to any keypress even the escape key and keeps running.

```
import keyboard


def dostuff():
    print("Mew")
    key = keyboard.read_key()
    print('I have detected', type(key))


keyboard.add_hotkey('a', lambda: dostuff())
keyboard.wait('esc')
```

Can anyone tell what's the issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to use the keyboard module, you can use pynput, which does the same thing,

install pynput using pip

```
pip install pynput
```

here is the code:-

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    try:
        print('alphanumeric key {0} pressed'.format(
            key.char))
    except AttributeError:
        print('special key {0} pressed'.format(
            key))

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} released'.format(
        key))
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        # Stop listener when esc key is pressed
        return False

# Collect events until released
with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: i want to detect a key press i dont know in advance which key will be pressed

Comment: You mean you want to save it?

Comment: without displaying it on the console?

Comment: example will explain better, user press 'a' hotkey say a then press a number key like 5 and then key 1 is required to access the value at index 1. so i need to press a then 1 to get access the value at index 1 like this

Comment: You can use if else statements to do that, just replace the print function to if else, if key == key_release: , get access